# phoenix socket multiple assign

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I want to add a few data into `socket` but wondering what the best way to do that would be.

Instead of doing a bunch of

`socket = assign(socket, :channel_id, channel_id)`

Comment: `socket |> assign(:channel_id, channel_id) |> assign(:channel_name, channel_name) |> ...`?

Answer (score 5):

There is an alternative function [`assign/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#assign/2) that allows assigning multiple values at once, by passing either map or keyword list:

```
assign(socket, name: "Elixir", logo: "")
assign(socket, %{name: "Elixir"})
```